# I have a htm file can i read it as UTF-8 formatted file without doing anything to the file

Tags: java

I have a htm file can i read it as UTF-8 formatted file without doing anything to the file.
the file is saved in unicode(not sure) i want to read it as UTF-8 file other wise it gives me some boxes.. this has to be done using java

```
FileReader loInput = new FileReader(loFile); 
BufferedReader loBufferReader = new BufferedReader(loInput); 
String loLine; // String that holds current loFile loLine 
int loCount = 0; // Line number of loCount 
loLine = loBufferReader.readLine(); 
loCount++; 
while (loLine != null) { 
    loContent = loContent.concat(loLine); 
    loLine = loBufferReader.readLine(); 
    loCount++; 
} 
loBufferReader.close();
```

i tried this

**EDIT:** i have to get the data from HTML file and convert it into a DOM object for further processing

I am using

```
SAXBuilder loSaxBuilder=new SAXBuilder();
            Reader loStringReader=new StringReader(loContent);
            Document loDoc=loSaxBuilder.build(loStringReader);
            XPath loXpath = XPath.newInstance("/Div");
            Element loElement = (Element) loXpath.selectSingleNode(loDoc);
```

to convert it to dom object

Comment: FileReader loInput = new FileReader(loFile);
    BufferedReader loBufferReader = new BufferedReader(loInput);
    String loLine;    // String that holds current loFile loLine
    int loCount = 0;  // Line number of loCount 
    loLine = loBufferReader.readLine();
    loCount++;
    while (loLine != null){
     loContent = loContent.concat(loLine);
     loLine = loBufferReader.readLine();
     loCount++;
    }
    loBufferReader.close();

i tried this

Comment: Put your code in your question and indent it with at least four spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done using :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.*;
public class CharsetToolkit{
private byte[] buffer;
private Charset defaultCharset;
private boolean enforce8Bit = false;
public CharsetToolkit(byte[] buffer)
{
    this.buffer = buffer;
    this.defaultCharset = getDefaultSystemCharset();
}
public CharsetToolkit(byte[] buffer, Charset defaultCharset)
{
    this.buffer = buffer;
    setDefaultCharset(defaultCharset);
}
public void setDefaultCharset(Charset defaultCharset)
{
    if (defaultCharset != null)
        this.defaultCharset = defaultCharset;
    else
        this.defaultCharset = getDefaultSystemCharset();
}
public void setEnforce8Bit(boolean enforce)

{

    this.enforce8Bit = enforce;

}

public boolean getEnforce8Bit()

{

    return this.enforce8Bit;

}

public Charset getDefaultCharset()
{
    return defaultCharset;
}

public Charset guessEncoding()
{
    if (hasUTF8Bom(buffer)) return Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    if (hasUTF16LEBom(buffer)) return Charset.forName("UTF-16LE");
if (hasUTF16BEBom(buffer)) return Charset.forName("UTF-16BE");
    boolean highOrderBit = false;
    boolean validU8Char = true;
int length = buffer.length;
    int i = 0;

while (i < length - 6)
    {
        byte b0 = buffer[i];
        byte b1 = buffer[i + 1];
        byte b2 = buffer[i + 2];
        byte b3 = buffer[i + 3];
        byte b4 = buffer[i + 4];
        byte b5 = buffer[i + 5];
        if (b0 < 0)

    {
        highOrderBit = true;
            // a two-bytes sequence was encoutered
            if (isTwoBytesSequence(b0))
            {
                if (!isContinuationChar(b1))
                validU8Char = false;
                else
                    i++;
            }
            // a three-bytes sequence was encoutered

            else if (isThreeBytesSequence(b0))

            {

                // there must be two continuation bytes of the form 10xxxxxx,

                // otherwise the following characteris is not a valid UTF-8 construct

                if (!(isContinuationChar(b1) && isContinuationChar(b2)))

                    validU8Char = false;

                else

                    i += 2;

            }

            // a four-bytes sequence was encoutered

            else if (isFourBytesSequence(b0))

            {

                // there must be three continuation bytes of the form 10xxxxxx,

                // otherwise the following characteris is not a valid UTF-8 construct

                if (!(isContinuationChar(b1) && isContinuationChar(b2) && isContinuationChar(b3)))

                    validU8Char = false;

                else

                    i += 3;

            }

            // a five-bytes sequence was encoutered

            else if (isFiveBytesSequence(b0))

            {

                // there must be four continuation bytes of the form 10xxxxxx,

                // otherwise the following characteris is not a valid UTF-8 construct

                if (!(isContinuationChar(b1) && isContinuationChar(b2) && isContinuationChar(b3) && isContinuationChar(b4)))

                    validU8Char = false;

                else

                    i += 4;

            }

            // a six-bytes sequence was encoutered

            else if (isSixBytesSequence(b0))

            {

                // there must be five continuation bytes of the form 10xxxxxx,

                // otherwise the following characteris is not a valid UTF-8 construct

                if (!(isContinuationChar(b1) && isContinuationChar(b2) && isContinuationChar(b3) && isContinuationChar(b4) && isContinuationChar(b5)))

                    validU8Char = false;

                else

                    i += 5;

            }

            else

                validU8Char = false;

        }

        if (!validU8Char) break;

        i++;

    }

    // if no byte with an high order bit set, the encoding is US-ASCII

    // (it might have been UTF-7, but this encoding is usually internally used only by mail systems)

    if (!highOrderBit)

    {

        // returns the default charset rather than US-ASCII if the enforce8Bit flag is set.

        if (this.enforce8Bit)

            return this.defaultCharset;

        else

            return Charset.forName("US-ASCII");

    }

    // if no invalid UTF-8 were encountered, we can assume the encoding is UTF-8,

    // otherwise the file would not be human readable

    if (validU8Char) return Charset.forName("UTF-8");

    // finally, if it's not UTF-8 nor US-ASCII, let's assume the encoding is the default encoding

    return this.defaultCharset;

}



public static Charset guessEncoding(File f, int bufferLength) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException

{

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];

    fis.read(buffer);

    fis.close();

    CharsetToolkit toolkit = new CharsetToolkit(buffer);

    toolkit.setDefaultCharset(getDefaultSystemCharset());

    return toolkit.guessEncoding();

}



public static Charset guessEncoding(File f, int bufferLength, Charset defaultCharset) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException

{

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];

    fis.read(buffer);

    fis.close();

    CharsetToolkit toolkit = new CharsetToolkit(buffer);

    toolkit.setDefaultCharset(defaultCharset);

    return toolkit.guessEncoding();

}



/**

 * If the byte has the form 10xxxxx, then it's a continuation byte of a multiple byte character;

 *

 * @param b a byte.

 * @return true if it's a continuation char.

 */

private static boolean isContinuationChar(byte b)

{

    return -128 <= b && b <= -65;

}



/**

 * If the byte has the form 110xxxx, then it's the first byte of a two-bytes sequence character.

 *

 * @param b a byte.

 * @return true if it's the first byte of a two-bytes sequence.

 */

private static boolean isTwoBytesSequence(byte b)

{

    return -64 <= b && b <= -33;

}



/**

 * If the byte has the form 1110xxx, then it's the first byte of a three-bytes sequence character.

 *

 * @param b a byte.

 * @return true if it's the first byte of a three-bytes sequence.

 */

private static boolean isThreeBytesSequence(byte b)

{

    return -32 <= b && b <= -17;

}



/**

 * If the byte has the form 11110xx, then it's the first byte of a four-bytes sequence character.

 *

 * @param b a byte.

 * @return true if it's the first byte of a four-bytes sequence.

 */

private static boolean isFourBytesSequence(byte b)

{

    return -16 <= b && b <= -9;

}
```

private static boolean isFiveBytesSequence(byte b)
    {
        return -8 <= b && b <= -5;
    }

```
private static boolean isSixBytesSequence(byte b)
{
    return -4 <= b && b <= -3;
}
public static Charset getDefaultSystemCharset()
{
    return Charset.forName(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
}
private static boolean hasUTF8Bom(byte[] bom)
{
    return (bom[0] == -17 && bom[1] == -69 && bom[2] == -65);
}
private static boolean hasUTF16LEBom(byte[] bom)
{
return (bom[0] == -1 && bom[1] == -2);
}
private static boolean hasUTF16BEBom(byte[] bom)
{
    return (bom[0] == -2 && bom[1] == -1);
}
public static Charset[] getAvailableCharsets()
{
    Collection collection = Charset.availableCharsets().values();
    return (Charset[]) collection.toArray(new Charset[collection.size()]);
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
File file = new File("windows-1252.txt");
    Charset guessedCharset = CharsetToolkit.guessEncoding(file, 4096);
    System.err.println("Charset found: " + guessedCharset.displayName());
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, guessedCharset);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(line);

    }}}
```

and by calling this

```
Charset guessedCharset = CharsetToolkit.guessEncoding(new File("filename.htm"), 4096);
    BufferedReader c = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("filename.htm"), guessedCharset)) ;
```

Comment: So you copied http://groovy.codehaus.org/xref/groovy/util/CharsetToolkit.html to guess the encoding of the file.

Comment: The question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream gives you a couple of answers, you should be using either http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GUESSENC/Home or http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/CharsetDetector.html or http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/ instead of pasting the class into your project.

Answer (score 3):

First, Unicode is not an encoding, but a family of encodings, of which UTF-8 is one.

Second, you could use something like

```
Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
```

And then read from `in` in a loop and append to a `StringBuilder` or `CharBuffer`, or write to a `StringWriter`, but it'd probably be easiest for you to just use [IOUtils.toString(InputStream,String) from Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-2.0/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29), which i recommend.

Comment: @varun: Also, it's possible that you won't need to have it in a String, it depends on what you're going to do with it. Tell us more please.

Comment: i have get the data from HTML file and convert it into a DOM object for further processing

Comment: @ Christoffer : can i have a code snippet for the same? couldnt get you

Comment: @varun: If you want to build a HTML DOM you need a HTML parser, and you wouldn't need the document in a String since the HTML parser would handle reading the stream for you. Which HTML parser are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can.

Using a `InputStreamReader` with the required unicode encoding (eg., `UTF-8`).

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDir), "UTF8"));
```