# Trying to write to file a char with ascii code more than 127 in JScript

Tags: windows, jscript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript, write to txt file save as UNICODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802867/javascript-write-to-txt-file-save-as-unicode)

I have a problem with writing to a TextStream char with code more than 127.

Example:

```
a.WriteLine(String.fromCharCode(130));
```

will return error. But

```
a.WriteLine(String.fromCharCode(65));
```

will write A. What is the problem?