# CreateTextfile() > write does not work

Tags: windows, vbscript

VBScript does delivers an "Illegal Argument" message when trying to write the text shown below to file using the following code. If I change resultStr to some test text, it works. What could be the problem?

```
Set resFile = fs.CreateTextfile(resFilePath, true)
resFile.write resultStr
resFile.close
```

---

Contents of resultStr:

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string looks like it contains non-ASCII characters. You need to pass an extra `True` argument to `CreateTextfile` to open the text file using a Unicode encoding (probably UTF-16 on Windows).

If you want to write UTF-8 to the file, see [Writing UTF8 text to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840252/writing-utf8-text-to-file).