# Write an empty file with just the UTF-8 BOM

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, batch-file, cmd

OS: Windows 7 SP1

I created an empty text file in the `cmd.exe` using the below command:

```
echo 2> .gitignore
```

The command redirects `std::cerr` (empty output in this case) into the `.gitignore` file. The result file has `ANSI` encoding, but I need `UTF-8`. Can I point the necessary encoding (`UTF-8`) for the `>` operation?

Comment: try calling `chcp 65001` (utf-8) before your command.

Comment: At this case my text file has ANSI encoding also.

Comment: "Encoding" is the property of file *content*. Empty file does not have any content, thus it does not have any encoding. If you want to write text in some encoding, then powershell's `Out-File` should do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible via batch-file output redirection.

The only way to do it with the built-in utilities is to invoke powershell:

```
powershell -c "[io.file]::WriteAllText('.gitignore','',[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)"
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it is the only way, but it certainly can't be done with Windows batch, and PowerShell is a good option.

Comment: "using built-in utilities" was on my mind at that moment, added it now.

Comment: I believe JScript could be used as well, and it is built-in and available to all versions of Windows since XP, without any special privileges or activation required.

Comment: Ah, indeed, strictly speaking you're right, however a [jscript solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840252/writing-utf8-text-to-file) isn't what I would like to endorse or even remember...

Comment: @dbenham it's possible with native batch, please see my answer

Answer (score 4):

Pure batch solution, based on [Generate nearly any character, including TAB, from batch](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3857#p20765) by dbenham

```
@echo off

(set LF=^
%=empty=%
)

::Create variables to store BOM bytes
call :hexprint "0xEF" EF
call :hexprint "0xBB" BB
call :hexprint "0xBF" BF

<nul SET /P "=%EF%%BB%%BF%"> output.txt
exit /b

:hexPrint  string  [rtnVar]
  for /f eol^=^%LF%%LF%^ delims^= %%A in (
    'forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(%~1"'
  ) do if "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%%A) else echo(%%A
exit /b
```

See also [Write HEX values to file in Windows batch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47750732/995714)

Answer (score 1):

Create a .bat/.cmd file like:

```
<nul SET /P "=123"> output.txt
```

Then replace 123 with EF BB BF bytes in your prefered HEX-editor.

To edit this .bat/.cmd file later one shouldn't use Window's Notepad.exe as it converts BOM-bytes to a question mark (`?`) in the "Save as ASCII" mode (or, in the "Save as UTF-8" mode it adds unneeded BOM to the script file itself).
Instead one can use Notepad++ with a "UTF-8 (witout BOM)" mode.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? If this works correctly, I don't see the problem. If you're messing around with batch files you'll probably be able to hex edit a file with not much problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hybrid batch - JScript solution. Just save as a batch file and run normally

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
cscript //e:jscript //nologo "%~f0" %1
exit /b

@end

// JScript Section

var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var file = fso.CreateTextFile(WScript.Arguments.Item(0), true);

file.Write(String.fromCharCode(239));
file.Write(String.fromCharCode(187));
file.Write(String.fromCharCode(191));
file.Close();
```

Same as above, but hybrid batch - VBS

```vb
<!-- : Begin batch script
@echo off
cscript //nologo "%~f0?.wsf" %1
exit /b

----- Begin wsf script --->
<job><script language="VBScript">
    Set fso  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set file = fso.CreateTextFile(WScript.Arguments.Item(0), true)

    file.Write Chr(239)
    file.Write Chr(187)
    file.Write Chr(191)
    file.Close
</script></job>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure batch to create an empty UTF-8 file with BOM:

```
set _FILE=output.txt
chcp 437 > nul
forfiles /c "cmd /c <nul set /p=0xEF0xBB0xBF>\"%_FILE%\"" > nul
chcp 65001 > nul
```

and to add lines:

```
>> "%_FILE%" (
    echo Line 1
    echo Line 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an empty text file with the BOM, which I copy, and then append the stuff I need in this file.

```
copy empty-bom.txt .gitignore
echo stuff>>.gitignore
```

I prefer this solution because it is so much more readable and understandable than all the other solutions that generate the BOM.

Answer (score -1):

This will give you utf 16, start `cmd` with `/u` switch

```
cmd /u /c type ansi.txt > uni.txt
```

`/u` make internal commands output UTF16.

Comment: Yes, but the OP explicitly asked for UTF-8. Not possible with native batch.